# Unknown problem with (probably) POST method

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

This task is quite simple but I just can't seem to get it to work. What the outcome should be is explained in the picture below. I guess that there is some kind of a problem with POST in php, but I'm not sure. Do you see what's the problem that's causing this not to work?

Problem: No results are shown when there should be.

[image]

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "podaci");
 
if($conn === false){
    die("Konekcija nije uspešna. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$number = $_POST['number']; 
$result_array = array();

/* SQL query to get results from database */
$sql = "SELECT brojKartice, imeVlasnika, prezimeVlasnika, adresaVlasnika, 
ostvareniBodovi, ostvareniPopust FROM podatak WHERE brojKartice = '".$number."' "; 

$result = $conn->query($sql);

/* If there are results from database push to result array */
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($result_array, $row);
    }
}
/* send a JSON encded array to client */
echo json_encode($result_array);

$conn->close();
?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "container" > 
       <strong>Unesite broj kartice: </strong><input id="number" name="number" required/>
    <input type="button" id="getusers" value="Provera"/> <br><br>
    <div id="records"></div>  
    </div> 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {
    $('#getusers').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'provera.php',
            data: {
                number: $('#number').val()
            }
        });
    });
});

    $(function(){ 
      $("#getusers").on('click', function(){ 
      $.ajax({ 
        method: "GET",   
        url: "provera.php",
      }).done(function( data ) { 
        var result= $.parseJSON(data); 

          var string='<table width="100%"><tr><th>#</th><th>Korisnik</th><th>Adresa</th><th>Bodovi</th><th>Popust</th><tr>';
 
 /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */
  $.each( result, function( key, value ) { 
    string += "<tr> <td>"+value['brojKartice'] + "</td><td>"+value['imeVlasnika']+' '+value['prezimeVlasnika']
      + "</td><td>"+value['adresaVlasnika']+ "</td><td>"+value['ostvareniBodovi']+ "</td><td>"
        +value['ostvareniPopust']+"</td> </tr>"; 
        }); 
       string += '</table>'; 
    $("#records").html(string);
       }); 
    }); 
});

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
CREATE DATABASE podaci;

CREATE TABLE podatak (
brojKartice VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
imeVlasnika VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
prezimeVlasnika VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
adresaVlasnika VARCHAR(50),
ostvareniBodovi VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
ostvareniPopust VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
rokVazenja DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO podatak VALUES
('0123456','Đorđe','Anđelković',NULL,'15','150','2021-1-9'),
('6543210','Snežana','Bojović',NULL,'20','200','2021-5-3'),
('9876543','Goran','Stojadinović',NULL,'10','100','2021-9-7'),
('3456789','Bojana','Marković',NULL,'25','250','2021-12-15');
```

Comment: Making a POST _and_ a GET request when clicking the button? What have you done to debug? Anything in the console? Network tab?

Comment: There should only be one click listener and one ajax call. Move the `done()` from second GET to the POST ajax. When you make multiple requests none of them know anything about the other and you need the data processed in the POST

Comment: @brombeer console just says this when I click the button - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.html:40)
    at i (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4)

Comment: Most likely because your script fails and doesn't return JSON. If you're making a GET request `$_POST['number']` will not be set -> query fails. Set `$number` to `'0123456'` and call the script. It probably fails at `$result = $conn->query($sql);` which should be `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);`

Comment: @charlietfl To be honest I wouldn't know how to do that properly this is my first day working with ajax so I'm still getting used to it. Could you please edit that part so I know how it's done.

Comment: You only want the post and to handle the JSON response that gets returned to it

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah I realised that after reading all the answers, I'm just trying to figure out after which bracket to paste it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome. Here are a few pointers to help you identify the source of the issue:

1. Is your browser making the HTTP requests that you expect? By glancing at your Javascript, you expect both a POST and a GET. If you are using Google Chrome, check [Dev tools - Network](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/)
2. What HTTP requests is the server receiving? You can debug your PHP code by [following the official debugging documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/debugger.php) and reading its comments. Especially:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

3. Is the server answering the data you are expecting? Check the HTTP verb (GET or POST) used to get the number (hint: line 8 of your code). Now check on which HTTP call (GET or POST) you put the Javascript callback to handle the server response.

Answer: your PHP code reads the number from the POST request, but your Javascript code only supports responses from the GET request.

Simplify your Javascript by moving the callback (the `function` block passed as argument of the `.done()` method) from the GET request to the POST request. Then delete the Javascript code dealing with the GET request.

Alternatively, replace $_POST with $_GET and remove the POST call.

Comment: Very informative. I will add that I did it exactly as you said and it worked, but only instead of replacing $_POST with $_GET I replaced $_GET with $_POST and removed GET call.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you have two event handler for **#getusers** button. This doesn't make sense in the first place. Whenever you assign multiple event handler on a html element only the last one will trigger. In this case, it's only the ajax call with the `GET` method. And on your server side (php), this variable `$number = $_POST['number'];`  will not have a value because the method was `GET`.

So to solve this you have two options I can think of:

#1. Move the first ajax call that you have where you have the `POST` request and then place it where you have the ajax call with `GET` method. In short, replace `GET` with `POST` event.

#2. Change your php code to use `$_GET` and update your ajax call for `GET` to adhere with the PHP change.

You can remove either of the event handler of your button and just bind only one.

Here is for a quick reference on javascript event handler and addEventListeners: https://gist.github.com/belmer/5e433aabbab24086af5c12ce0fb7323c

Best regards,

Comment: *"only the last one will trigger"* ... That is not true. Example https://jsfiddle.net/syvzcw7a/

Comment: This is because you are using jquery. This is called jquery method chaining. This is possible because most of the jQuery methods return a jQuery object that can be further used to call another method.

Comment: The chaining is irrelevant. Elements can have numerous event listeners for same event. You can do exact same thing with `addEventListener()`

Comment: That's what I was saying. If you use `addEventListener()` you can have multiple BUT if event handler you can have as much as you want but will only trigger the last one added.

Comment: No... each will be triggered. Same thing using native listener, each gets triggered https://jsfiddle.net/swbv94mo/

Comment: Those are **eventListeners** not event handlers. Here https://jsfiddle.net/z0rwda6o/

Comment: Well actually a handler is a function that gets called when event occurs. Yes you can only assign one function to the `onclick` property but that is not what is being done in question. Your statement is still not correct because there can be more than one listener

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. But just for the record I did not say that you can't have multiple listeners. I said multiple event handlers. But I'll take that because I might not be clear of my statements. Peace!